# Calling a stored procedure in Oracle with IN and OUT parameters

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1(invoicenr IN NUMBER, amnt OUT NUMBER)
AS BEGIN
SELECT AMOUNT INTO amnt FROM INVOICE WHERE INVOICE_NR = invoicenr;
END;
```

So when I run it like this it returns absolutely nothing:

```
DECLARE
    amount NUMBER;
BEGIN
    PROC1(1000001, amount);
    dbms_output.put_line(amount);
END;
```

BTW I use DreamCoder for Oracle. Is there a problem with the procedure itself or with the way I call it? There is an entry in the INVOICE table with INVOICE_NR equal to 1000001.

Comment: If you run "begin dbms_output.put_line('output test') end;" do you see the output? This procedure and way of calling it is totally correct.

Comment: I run it this way but I don't see the output. Is it possible that DreamCoder doesn't show the output of put_line()?

Comment: No I tried with`BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('hi');
END;` and it doesn't show anything either.

Answer (score 77):

If you set the server output in ON mode before the entire code, it works, otherwise put_line() will not work. Try it!

The code is,

```
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1(invoicenr IN NUMBER, amnt OUT NUMBER)
AS BEGIN
SELECT AMOUNT INTO amnt FROM INVOICE WHERE INVOICE_NR = invoicenr;
END;
```

And then call the function as it is:

```
DECLARE
amount NUMBER;
BEGIN
PROC1(1000001, amount);
dbms_output.put_line(amount);
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.  I used a trigger and in that trigger I called a procedure which computed some values into 2 OUT variables.  When I tried to print the result in the trigger body, nothing showed on screen.  But then I solved this problem by making 2 local variables in a function, computed what I need with them and finally, copied those variables in your OUT procedure variables.  I hope it'll be useful and successful!

Comment: Same works for .NET: when I call Oracle procs from .net., unless I select into local variables, and then pass local variables values to the OUT variables, I get null returned.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Menu Tool -> SQL Output, Run the PL/SQL statement, 
the output will show on SQL Output panel.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, a colon (":") should precede any output variable while executing stored procedures, so invocation should look like this: `PROC1(1000001, :amount);`

```
DECLARE
    amount NUMBER;
BEGIN
    PROC1(1000001, :amount);
    dbms_output.put_line(amount);
END;
/
```

hope this helps