# How can a stored procedure be executed in Oracle with in and out parameters?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Here's my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE STATS_SD 
(
  P_ID IN NUMBER,
  PRC OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN PRC FOR
  SELECT
    ID,
    SESID
  FROM RESPONSES
  WHERE ID IN (P_ID)
END;
```

When I try to execute it using

```
EXEC EXAM_STATS_STUDENTS_SD('6901');
```

I get the following error:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'STATS_SD'

Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Did you do some research? There's some similar questions in SO, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024771/calling-a-stored-procedure-in-oracle-with-in-and-out-parameters

Comment: your procedure is `STATS_SD` and it accepts **2** parameters ... so what are you exactly  executing with `EXAM_STATS_STUDENTS_SD('6901')` ?

Comment: Having a procedure with one out parameter might be a good candidate for a function.

Comment: Your input parameter is NUMBER, you pass a VARCHAR2 in the exec command

Comment: My bad. I used the number without the quotes initially and just tried using it with quotes. It doesn't work without quotes either :(

Comment: @RicardoPontual I did have a look at this question. However, using set serveroutput on; gives me another error: missing or invalid option

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a wrong datatype to your procedure.

According to your declaration a `NUMBER` is expected:

```
 P_ID IN NUMBER
```

However, you pass a VARCHAR2 in your exec command:

```
EXEC EXAM_STATS_STUDENTS_SD('6901');
```

Note the `''` around the value.
Try calling this instead:

```
EXEC EXAM_STATS_STUDENTS_SD(6901);
```

Apart from that you are missing the second parameter completely.

Comment: The second parameter is the OUT parameter. How can I provide it if I want to get it from the SP? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using an OUT parameter that is a sys_refcursor.  Note that I close the cursor in the pl/sql block that uses it (which is important!):

```
create or replace procedure get_data(o_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) as
begin
  OPEN o_cur FOR
  select * from emp;
end;
```

And using the get_data procedure:

```
declare
  l_cur sys_refcursor;
  l_row emp%rowtype;
begin
  get_data(l_cur);
  LOOP
    fetch l_cur
    into l_row;
    exit when l_cur%notfound;
    -- do something with l_row here

  END LOOP;
  close l_cur;
end;
```