# How to correctly call a SQL stored procedure using R's DBI library?

Tags: sql, r, oracle

Below I have a stored procedure created in Oracle. I've cut out the majority of the middle and am just focusing on the input and output:

```sql
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE datatrans_n.dc_cpt_patient_new
           -- Declaring input and output.
           ( p_study_id               IN patient.study_id%TYPE,
             p_subject                IN patient.subject%TYPE,
             p_subject_dict           IN patient.subject_dict%TYPE,
             p_site                   IN patient.site%TYPE,
             p_cancer_type            IN patient.cancer_type%TYPE,
             p_comments               IN patient.comments%TYPE,
             ps_patient_status_name   IN patient_status.patient_status%TYPE,
             pml_link_date            IN NVARCHAR2,
             status                   OUT NUMBER ) ...
  -- Returning 1 if successful.
  status := SQL%rowcount;
  -- Committing.
  COMMIT;
ELSE
  -- Returning 0 if unsuccessful.
  status := 0;
END IF;
-- Raising exceptions.
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
  NULL;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ROLLBACK;
  RAISE;
END dc_cpt_patient_new;
/
```

And I'm attempting to call this stored procedure in R using the DBI library like so:

```
# Creating SQL.
query <- DBI::sqlInterpolate(
  conn = con,
  sql = "DECLARE STATUS NUMBER; 
         BEGIN 
               DATATRANS_N.DC_CPT_PATIENT_NEW(?study_id, ?subject, ?subject_dict, ?site, 
                                              ?cancer_type, ?comments, ?patient_status, 
                                              ?icf_date, STATUS); 
         END;",
  .dots = hold_patient[c("study_id", "subject", "subject_dict", "site", 
                         "cancer_type", "comments", "patient_status", "icf_date")]
)

# Executing SQL.
return <- DBI::dbExecute(con, query)
```

The issue is that when executing my SQL query, I'm not correctly capturing the value of `STATUS` in my stored procedure in my R variable `return`. I've tested this by editing the line `Status := SQL%ROWCOUNT;` to `Status := 3; --SQL%ROWCOUNT;`, and both times `return` has a value of 1.

How can I call this stored procedure so that I can capture the value of `STATUS` in `return`?

Comment: What if you replaced `dbExecute` with `dbGetQuery` ? dbExecute will return the number of affected rows, while dbGetQuery will actually give you the result of the query.

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130924/1422451) advising the use of `serveroutput` and `dbms_output.put_line`.