# Oracle stored procedure to drop multiple indexes with input and output params

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I need to develop 2 Oracle stored procedures, one to drop an index and other to create indexes, so that I can call them from within my application.

I tried something like this -- but my applications says it doesn't have output params and it also has error at parallel option

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CLEAR_INDEX(INDEX_NAME1 IN VARCHAR2, INDEX_NAME2 IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop index ' || INDEX_NAME1 'parallel';
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop index ' || INDEX_NAME2 'parallel';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL;
END CLEAR_INDEX;
```

Comment: also, i'm using a application called Denodo, which will only import an Oracle SP with input and output params

Comment: You could always include output as boolean with t/f value.

Comment: Error with parallel option is because you forgot to use concatenation operator. Change it to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop index ' || INDEX_NAME2 || ' parallel';`

Comment: Thank you can u plz provide me the syntax with the output Boolean param please

Comment: There are many examples on the net and stackoverflow. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183377/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-with-output-parameter-in-oracle-pl-sql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024771/calling-a-stored-procedure-in-oracle-with-in-and-out-parameters

Comment: sorry i couldn't find a way to return a Boolean value logic

Comment: this procedure does not even compile, you did not mention this and did not show the error message. why is this comment in the source?

Comment: [Oracle 12.2 documentation for `drop index`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/DROP-INDEX.html). There is no `parallel` option.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question correctly, you want to drop and create the index, then return boolean true if the index operations succeed, or false if they fail. The natural construct here is a FUNCTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CLEAR_INDEX
   (   INDEX_NAME1 IN VARCHAR2,
       INDEX_NAME2 IN VARCHAR2 )
   RETURN BOOLEAN AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop index ' || INDEX_NAME1;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop index ' || INDEX_NAME2;
    RETURN ( TRUE ):
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN ( FALSE );
END CLEAR_INDEX;
```

If you insist on PROCEDURE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CLEAR_INDEX
   (   INDEX_NAME1 IN VARCHAR2,
       INDEX_NAME2 IN VARCHAR2,
       IT_WORKED   OUT BOOLEAN )
BEGIN
    IT_WORKED := FALSE;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop index ' || INDEX_NAME1;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop index ' || INDEX_NAME2;
    IT_WORKED := TRUE;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       IT_WORKED := FALSE;
END CLEAR_INDEX;
```

Note how the `parallel` option was removed because there is no such thing as a parallel drop.  Dropping objects usually happens immediately, there is no reason to parallelize the operation.

Comment: Teng..Thank you sir. Is there any other way to declare the output parameter. It works fine in Oracle. But some how my 3rd party application.. complain about lack of input/output parameters..

Comment: The "IT_WORKED" parameter is exactly that - the output parameter. You haven't described what your 3rd party system is, so am unable to help. Are you asking for how tto handle the out parameter in the 3rd party system? If so will need to know what code snippet you have tried,

Comment: makes sense.. I will use Parallel while re-recreating them back

Comment: when i call the above SP as below i get below error any advice..CALL schema.SPname(@INDEX_NAME1, @INDEX_NAME2)... java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 30:
PLS-00201: identifier 'INDEX1' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: how do we execute the above SP.. i get error as CLEAR_INDEX#0 [JDBC ROUTE] [ERROR]  Received exception with message 'ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CLEAR_INDEX'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored'