# Satisfied complicated condition then doing something

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have three scenario, if all are satisfied then doing something.

1. `select count(*) from schema.member where condition1` is 0
2. `select id from schema.ta a, schema.b where a.id=b.id and a.id !='input_id' and a.id in ('M','N');`   it should be null or not existing.
3. `select member from schema.tc, x schema.tb where condition3`; it also should be null or not existing.

So basically if all 3 scenarios are all met, then I will do something.

I want to use a stored procedure to do it. My idea is
get an integer from the sum of count of each scenario; if it is 0 then all are satisfied.

Like `select count(id) from schema.member where condition1
     + select count(id) from ... where condition2
     + select count(member) from ... where condition3 = 0`

Not sure what is the best way and script assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, and there are several tables involved. Would you please post sample data and expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put all of them into  `NOT EXISTS` checks

```
DECLARE
     l_flag   INTEGER;
BEGIN
     SELECT
          CASE
               WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM schema.member
                    WHERE condition1 = 'somecondition'
               ) AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM schema.ta a
                    JOIN schema.b ON a.id = b.id --use proper join syntax
                             WHERE a.id != 'input_id' AND a.id IN ('M','N') 
                             AND a.id IS NOT NULL -- no nulls as you said.
               ) AND NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM schema.tc
                    JOIN schema.tb ON condition3 = '<somecondition>'
                    WHERE member IS NOT NULL -- no nulls as you said.
               ) THEN 1
               ELSE 0
          END
     INTO l_flag
     FROM dual;

     IF
          l_flag = 1
     THEN
          do_something;
     END IF;
END;
/
```

I've shown an anonymous block. the same you could write within a procedure.

Comment: Thank you, I want return `1_flag` from the stored procedure. I want to use that value in my WCF code(I will convert it from sql to C#). If it is 0 then doing something. So can we return it in stored procedure? I don't want to use function.

Comment: @Bigeyes : You're welcome. I don't know about C# , but you may create a procedure and pass it as an out variable, using the contents of `begin..end` in my code. Look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130924)  to know how to use an OUT parameter. You may ask a separate question if you face difficulties with your code using appropriate c# tag. I hope I answered your original question. Please consider accepting it as it would also help others.

Comment: I marked it as the answer. But any right parenthesis missing?